Oven control location
I currently have a gas oven front controls and over the years I've had to replace the control board at least twice because of how hot the oven gets pretty much killing the control board. Looking to get a a new gas oven and wondering do the freestanding with the controls in the back have better longevity when it comes to the control board not overheating? Any opinions repairman out there or anybody knows? Thanks !

questions asking for an opinion are not allowed here, because all answers would be correct... how would you choose which of the opinions is the correct one?
